# Data binding setOnClickListener not called

Tags: android, binding

I making the Android Kotlin tutorial on Udacity, but my code does not work as expected. Please take a look on my code why does not work. The problem is the `binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener` not running.

This is my MainActivity.kt

```
package hu.webfeszek.aboutme

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
// import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import hu.webfeszek.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener {
            // This code does running never
            Log.i("LOG_ME", binding.doneButton.text.toString())
            addNickName(it)
        }
    }

    private fun addNickName(view:View) {
    }
}
```

I added the `<layout>` to my activity_main.xml and the 3 lines to build.gradle:

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

Comment: share your xml.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you rebuild the project every time you change something when using data binding because you need to generate code for every change you make.
If you are using Android Studio do a project rebuild.
Also remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` You don't need this line since you're using databinding.

Also, your xml button should look something like this:

```
     <Button
            android:text="Done"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/done_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>
```

Your Kotlin class onCreate:

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

    binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener {
        addNickname(view:View)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yes, It looks like this. When I remove this `binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)` the app is crashed. But I found in the generated file there is an error: `Duplicate class found in the file activity_main.xml`

Comment: Do not remove `binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main) `

instead remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

This is how your onCreate should look like

`override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
       

        binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener {
           //do stuff
}`

Comment: Awesome! Good luck.